# Isolate a term in a line

Tags: regex, bash, shell, variables

I would like to isolate a term in a specific line defined as follow :

```
enO.u16LINK=0x01
```

I succeed in isolate 0x01 by using `value=${lines##*=}`.
At the same time I succeed in retrieve `enO.u16LINK` using `${lines%=*}`.
However, I do not find how to isolate `enO` and `u16LINK` in two different variable.

Somebody knows a regular expression to satisfy this need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same thing you did already again.

```
$ lines=enO.u16LINK=0x01
$ value=${lines##*=}
$ key=${lines%=*}
$ key1=${key%.*}
$ key2=${key#*.}
$ echo value=$value
value=0x01
$ echo key=$key
key=enO.u16LINK
$ echo key1=$key1
key1=enO
$ echo key2=$key2
key2=u16LINK
```

Comment: Thank Etan ! Your solution is exactly that I searched.

Answer (score 2):

Using a subshell:

```
$ read a b c <<< $(IFS=".="; set -- $line; IFS=" "; echo "$*")
$ echo $a
enO
$ echo $b
u16LINK
$ echo $c
0x01
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cut ...

```
$ var1=`echo enO.u16LINK=0x01 | cut -d\= -f1 | cut -d\. -f1`
$ echo $var1
enO
$ var2=`echo enO.u16LINK=0x01 | cut -d\= -f1 | cut -d\. -f2`
$ echo $var2
u16LINK
```

Comment: Thank Red. Just a last question. In your solution -f1 is associated to the first term, before -d\= and -d\., and -f2 to the second one, isn't it ?

Comment: read the man page. `man cut`:)